# pandas convert a column to datetime but its type is not datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I need to convert a dataframe colmun to datetime in pandas.
But, its data type is not what I expect.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['2009-11-27'], columns = ['my_col'])
>>> df.dtypes['my_col']
dtype('O')
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['my_col'], format='%Y-%m-%d',  errors = 'coerce')
 0   2009-11-27
 Name: my_col, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> df.dtypes['my_col']
dtype('O')
>>> df['my_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['my_col'], format='%Y-%m-%d',  errors = 'coerce')
>>> df.dtypes['my_col']
dtype('<M8[ns]')
 >>> df['my_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['my_col'], format='%Y-%m-%d',  errors = 'coerce')
  >>> df.dtypes['my_col']
  dtype('<M8[ns]')
  >>> df = pd.DataFrame(['2009-11-27'], columns = ['my_col'])
  >>> df['my_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['my_col'], format='%Y-%m-%d',  errors = 'coerce')
  >>> df.dtypes['my_col']
 dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

I need to get the data type of the column so that my code can do

```
 if df.dtypes['my_col'] in (np.datetime64, datetime.datetime):
      do something .....
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Query the column's `dtype` attribute directly, you can do something like

```
df['my_col'].dtype
# dtype('<M8[ns]')

np.issubdtype(df['my_col'].dtype, np.datetime64)
# True
```

Comment: thanks, what if I have many columns, how to check all columns' type all together in one "np.issubdtype()" expression ?

Comment: @user3448011 `df[['a' 'b', 'c', ...]].dtypes.map(lambda x: np.issubdtype(x, np.datetime64)).all()` should return `True` if the condition is satisfied. But perhaps you might just want `df.select_dtypes(include=[np.datetime64])` if you are _selecting_ the columns.

Comment: I have many columns: int, float, string, datetime, I need  to do different things based on its data type. e.g. for all datetime columns, I do something. for all int columns, I do another things.

Comment: @user3448011 alright, is there something else I can do for you?

Answer (score 1):

using series with `dtypes`

```
df.iloc[0,:].dtypes
dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Or

```
df.select_dtypes(include=[np.datetime64, 'datetime' ,'datetime64'])
```

---

With `select_dtypes`, you code can be

```
df1=df.select_dtypes(include=[np.datetime64, 'datetime' ,'datetime64'])
do something
df2=df.drop(df1.columns,1)
do somthing
```

Answer (score 0):

`pd.to_datetime` is not inplace. You basically had it - just have to reassign the column after converting datetimes.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['2009-11-27'], columns = ['my_col'])
>>> df.dtypes['my_col']
dtype('O')
>>> df.my_col = pd.to_datetime(df['my_col'], format='%Y-%m-%d',  errors = 'coerce')
>>> df.dtypes['my_col']
dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

You can use this to check whether a column is a certain type - pandas dtypes are really just numpy dtypes.

```py
>>> type(df.my_col.dtype)
<class 'numpy.dtype'>
```

You can find [the list of numpy dtypes here.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

So that means you can make comparisons like this -

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df.dtypes['my_col'] == np.dtype('<M8[ns]')
True
>>> df.dtypes['my_col'] == np.dtype('<M8[ms]')
False
>>> df.dtypes['my_col'] in [np.dtype('<M8[ns]'), np.dtype('<M8[ms]')]
True
```